# How to config Sonar notification email?

Tags: email, hyperlink, notifications, format, sonarqube

Sonar send notifications by email which contains a link. This link isn't always correct when I changed default configurations, example: when I changed the port from 9000 to 8088, email give always the default port like this localhost:9000...
How can I change this link? Can I make my personal email format?

Answer (score 13):

To fix the links, open the web UI's Settings area, and under the "General" section, set the "Server base URL" value so that links in generate emails, etc, point to the right location. This can also be set in your sonar.properties file as sonar.core.serverBaseURL

Don't forget to restart the Sonar service for the changes to take effect.